# Orthonormal basis for $W_j$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, wavelets

Given $\{V_j: j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is multi-resolution analysis in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $W_0$ is an orthogonal complement of $V_0$ relative to $V_1$.

So that we can write, $V_1 = V_0 \bigoplus W_0$.
For every $j \in \mathbb{Z}$, define $$W_j = \{f(2^j x): f \in W_0\}.$$

How can I show:

if $\{ \psi(x-k): k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $W_0$, then for every $j \in \mathbb{Z}$, the set $$\{2^{j/2}\psi(2^jx-k): k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ is an orthonormal basis for $W_j$?

Can I use induction method? Or are there any methods that can be used effectively? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems? The computational part is to show that this is an orthonormal system, with emphasis on the "normal" part. The theoretical part is to show the completeness, however that is inherited directly from $W_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we show that $g\in W_0$ if and only if $g(2^j\cdot)\in W_j$ for $j\in \mathbb{Z}$. Since
$$V_1=V_0\oplus W_0$$
then $g\in W_0$ if and only if $g\in V_1$ and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\overline{f}(x)dx=0,\,\forall f\in V_0$$
Also since
$$V_{j+1}=V_{j}\oplus W_{j}$$
then $\tilde{g}\in W_{j}$ if and only if  $\tilde{g}\in V_{j+1}$ and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{g}(x)\overline{f}dx=0,\, \forall f\in V_j.$$
Now observe that $g\in V_0$ if and only if $g(2^j\cdot)\in V_j$ and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\overline{f}(x)dx=0\Leftrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(2x)\overline{f}(2x)dx=0.$$
So we proved
$$g\in W_0 \text{ if and only if } g(2^j\cdot)\in W_j\text{ for } j\in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Since $\{\varphi(\cdot-k):k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is an ortonormal basis for $W_0$ then
$$g(x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \alpha_k \varphi(x-k)$$
where the sum is finite. So
$$g(2^jx)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} 2^{-j/2}\alpha_k 2^{j/2}\varphi(2^jx-k).$$
So we proved they generate $W_j$. With a change of variables you prove they have norm one and also
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x-k)\overline{\varphi}(x-m)dx=0\Leftrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(2^jx-k)\overline{\varphi}(2^jx-m)dx=0.$$
Therefore, $\{2^{j/2}\varphi(2^jx-k):k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $W_j$.